# Automated DNS subnet mapping

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, openvpn

I have a remote network with subnets 192.168.0.0/24, 192.168.1.0/24, and 192.168.2.0/24. I have already configured a vm with openvpn which uses iptables' `NETMAP` to map 10.8.0.0/22 to 192.168.0.0/22. Now I want to map the DNS, (e.g. i have 192.168.2.10 for example.local, and i want to get 10.8.2.10 for example.local when connecting from vpn). I thought about adding another DNS on openvpn box, but didn't find any server that could do that. Can it be done without adding records in original DNS?

UPD: i'm using dnsmasq as a dns

Comment: http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/dns/ch10_06.htm